# Joomla "Add new article" javascript error "Joomla not defined"

Tags: javascript, joomla, joomla-article, joomla-content-editor

I recently tried to update my Joomla version from 2.5.8 to 2.5.11.

I encountered some problems so I decided to restore from a backup and I got the site back to 2.5.8.

Now my site works (frontend and backend) except for the editor (JCE).
The page loads for a while and then stops with the following javascript error:

> NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://www.isathens.gr/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=edit
>
> index....ut=edit
>
> ReferenceError: Joomla is not defined
>
> Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)

I am not very familiar with Joomla and I looked into the problem, but I cannot find a solution.

Comment: What kind of backup? HOw did you restore?

Comment: I used a backup from my server provider. I used it before for a migration and worked fine.

Comment: For your information, these types of questions are welcome at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.